# Android : Start Activity after button animation

Tags: java, android, animation, onclicklistener, start-activity

I used an android [library](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3954) to make a submit button with a nice animation (code below), after pressing the button, a want to start a new activity, but only after the animation is finished, how do i do that?

Xml code for the button "submitButton":

```
<com.spark.submitbutton.SubmitButton
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:textColor="@color/gray"
        app:sub_btn_background="@color/white"
        app:sub_btn_duration="3000"
        app:sub_btn_line_color="#99FF00"
        app:sub_btn_ripple_color="#99FF00"
        app:sub_btn_tick_color="@color/white"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/submitButton" />
```

Submit button for java file and action listener :

```
 SubmitButton submitButton = (SubmitButton) findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,ListViewActivity.class));
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that custom button doesn't provide a listener for its animation, there's no way to know when its animation is done.

Alternatively, you could use the duration of that animation, and start your activity in a `postDelayed(runnable, duration)`

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,ListViewActivity.class));
        }
    }, duration);
```

You may also replace the `new Handler()` with the `v` from `onClick(View v)`

Comment: It's right there in the XML sub_btn_duration="3000".

Answer (score 2):

Rather than start the activity directly, wrap up the call  in a runnable, and call postDelayed with 3000 ms delay.
Like this

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Runnable r = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
       {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,ListViewActivity.class));
        }
    }
    v.postDelayed(r, 3000);
}
```